# How to fill in empty double value in test DTO, Java, Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, testing, controller

So I am testing the controller of my application and I stumbled upon a problem.

This is the Json I use in my testcode:

```
String bike = "{" +
                "   \"bikeNumber\" : \"E2\"," +
                "   \"brand\" : \"Gazelle\"," +
                "   \"frameNumber\" : \"HA1234568\"," +
                "   \"retailPrice\" : 1200," +
                "   \"basePrice\" : 20.0," +
                "   \"electric\" : true" +
                "}";
```

I want to test when the user doesn't fill in one of the values, it throws an exception. In other words I want to test the @NotNull, @NotBlank annotations.
I have done this for bikeNumber and frameNumber, these are string types and I can leave them open. The problem I get if I leave the basePrice open and run my test, I get an error saying:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.basePrice"
```

I know that it's a null value because I haven't filled it in, but that is part of the plan. So my question is, how do I leave a long, double or int value empty without getting a test error.
My full code block is here:

```
  @Test
void whenPostRequestNoBasePrice_thenBadRequestResponse() throws Exception {


    String bike = "{" +
            "   \"bikeNumber\" : \"E1\"," +
            "   \"brand\" : \"Gazelle\"," +
            "   \"frameNumber\" : \"HA1234568\"," +
            "   \"retailPrice\" : 1200," +
            "   \"basePrice\" :  \"\" " +
            "   \"electric\" : true" +
            "}";
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/createbike")
            .content(bike)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.basePrice", Is.is( "Base price is mandatory.")))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
}
```

I tried multiple things, also with and without the comma:  "basePrice" :  "" ," +
Also I can't seem to find this anywhere on stackoverflow.

Comment: A primitive (`long`, `double` etc.) cannot be empty they always have a value. Only the object wrappers (`Long`, `Double` etc.) can be `null`.

Comment: @M.Deinum so it's not testable the way I want it to?

Comment: Not if they are primitives as mentioned before.